# Arquillian ShrinkWrap Web Archive created differently in different environments

Tags: maven, jenkins, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I am creating a war file using ShrinkWrap and it works correctly in my development environment when running tests through eclipse and through m2eclipse (maven).

When I run it on Jenkins the war deployment is different and so the tests fail. For example, I am adding custom MANIFEST.MF in the war as manifest resource which is empty on the war created in Jenkins environment.

Any ideas?

Edit: I have tried many different ways to add the MANIFEST.MF, the original code was:

```
 return ShrinkWrap
        .create(WebArchive.class, warName)
        .addClass(DbCleanupManager.class)
        .addAsLibraries(resolveBasicDependencies())
        .addAsWebInfResource(new File(TEST_RESOURCES, "jboss-deployment-structure.xml"))
        .addAsResource("version.properties", "version.properties")
        .addAsResource("logback-test.xml", "logback.xml")
        .addAsManifestResource("MANIFEST.MF");
```

But I have also tried:

```
.setManifest(
     new StringAsset(
     "Dependencies: org.apache.ws.security,org.apache.cxf,org.apache.cxf.impl,org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-client\n"));
```

And also trying deleting the MANIFEST.MF first (if it was added by ShrinkWrap) and then adding it to the archive i.e.:

```
WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap
        .create(WebArchive.class, warName)
        .addClass(DbCleanupManager.class)
        .addAsLibraries(resolveBasicDependencies())
        .addAsWebInfResource(new File(TEST_RESOURCES, "jboss-deployment-structure.xml"))
        .addAsResource("version.properties", "version.properties")
        .addAsResource("logback-test.xml", "logback.xml");

    war.delete(ArchivePaths.create("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
    war.addAsManifestResource("MANIFEST.MF");
```

By the way, all the above works fine in my local environment

UPDATE:

I noticed that the only difference between the two wars was the dependency arquillian-jacoco. I forgot that in Jenkins I run the tests using a profile which runs coverage using jacoco.

So the moment I remove the dependenycy (not the profile) the tests pass, the MANIFEST.MF is created correctly.

I suppose that means that jacoco extension somehow messes up MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: Jacoco does attempt to remove any signature references from the MANIFEST.MF to avoid Security errors loading the wrong classes. Could be something in there..

Comment: When you say Jacoco you mean the arquillian extension? Because I only commented out the extension, Jacoco still runs in my build.

Comment: So, in SignatureRemover class of arquillian-jacoco extension line 48:

archive.add(new ManifestAsset(original), entry.getKey());

should add the manifest file again in the archive. It seems that it doesn't or probably it adds an empty file called MANIFEST.MF and not the original. I don't think I can get any deeper than that

Comment: It seems to add an empty file. Could you please file a issue? jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/ARQ